# How do i make big string with batch code to execute in python?

Tags: python, string, shell, cmd, subprocess

been hours trying to fix this. Im trying to create a variable in python with my batch code as long string (`"""`) ex:

```
commands = """color b  

    /s /f /q c:\windows\temp\*.* 

 

    rd /s /q c:\windows\temp

       

    md c:\windows\temp

  

              
    del /s /f /q C:\WINDOWS\Prefetch

   

    del /s /f /q %temp%\*.* 

   

    rd /s /q %temp%

    md %temp%

    deltree /y c:\windows\tempor~1

    deltree /y c:\windows\temp

    deltree /y c:\windows\tmp

    deltree /y c:\windows\ff*.tmp

    deltree /y c:\windows\history
    deltree /y c:\windows\cookies
    deltree /y c:\windows\recent
    deltree /y c:\windows\spool\printers
    del c:\WIN386.SWP
    cls 
    FOR /F "tokens=1, 2 * " %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V
    IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin
    for /F " tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")
    echo.
    echo Quick dett ^<press any key^>
    :do_clear
    echo clearing %1
    
        wevtutil.exe cl %1
    
        goto :eof
    
        :noAdmin
    
    echo bot !
    echo ^<press any key^>
    cls
    pause"""
```

Its a simple cache cleaner, well my main goal is that the whole code block get executed, im just gettin output about color b into python terminal, other commands dont even execute.

Then i "sort" commands so i can execute them with `subprocess.Popen`

```
commandlist = shlex.split(commands)
```

But when i try to `subprocess.Popen(commandlist, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` just colorb get output

Comment: Btw sorry for terrible indentation

Comment: You will need to either write this to a file and execute it or write it as a single line command that you can pass to cmd.exe /C ...

Comment: as already mentioned Popen is not design to execute script. Try to split that string into a list of substrings and then try with a for loop

Comment: @cards, it's only on Windows where it can't handle scripts -- it's not a Popen limitation, it's a cmd.exe limitation.

Comment: @Charles Duffy good to know than, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responses guys, i was already going crazy

Comment: What kind of batch file is this? are you sure it works stand-alone? There is no `deltree` command on any modern Windows system, it was available on DOS-based Windows versions like 95, 98 and maybe ME, but never on Windows NT/2k/XP/Vista/7/8/10, as far as I know…

Comment: Its made to actually work on every system so it has to try these commands & its exactly like you pointed                                                                                                           Fun fact: they took like 10 years to relase deltree command on Dos-Based systems

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess module does not execute scripts, but only single commands. Put your script in a separate file (where it will be easier to maintain anyway) and execute using a command line like `cmd.exe externalscript.bat`

To be clear, this is a `cmd.exe` limitation so it applies only on Windows. UNIX/Linux shells can execute entire scripts this way. In fact, if you have `bash` installed on Windows (e.g. via WSL or Git) it'll work fine on Windows too, though you'll need to invoke the shell directly rather than using `shell=True`. I think PowerShell might work too, though I haven't tried it.

(Personally, I'd be tempted to rewrite the batch script in Python...)

Comment: The answer should probably be explicit that this is a Windows-only limitation. On platforms where `shell=True` prepends `['sh', '-c']` to the argument list, one can very much pass multiple commands in the code that gets interpreted.

Comment: Yeah i were kinda lost bcs of that i think, every forum i looked deep into claims that you can execute multiple commands that way, no one really specify it isnt available for w

Comment: Yes, true, it's a `cmd.exe` limitation.

Comment: Btw just want to point out: You can run scripts with subprocess module, for ex              `a = subprocess.Popen("myscript.bat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`